# Proving open formula

Tags: logic

Here $x,y$ are just real numbers.
If given an open formula like $\forall x (y=5x)$, how do we prove that the resultant closed formulae are false for all possible choices of $y$?
The way I think to do it is to write $\forall x \forall y (y=5x)$, then set $x$ to be $1$ giving $\forall y (y=5)$ which is false.

Comment: Usually y=5x says $\forall x\in R  \exists y \in R : y=5x$ so its not " false for all possible choices of " So what exactly is your question?

Comment: Something like $\neg(0=1)$ implies $\forall y\ \neg(y=5\frac{y+1}{5})$ implies $\forall y\exists x\ \neg(y=5x)$ implies $\forall y\ \neg(\forall x(y=5x))$, for example.

Comment: I'm talking about leaving $y$ as a free variable @trula.

Comment: $\forall x(y = 5x)$ is already false. You are duplicating your own question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749771/open-statements-in-first-order-logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this question was inspired by [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749447/differences-between-free-and-bounded-variables-in-a-statement/4749561?noredirect=1#comment10081641_4749561) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4749771/open-statements-in-first-order-logic) about the truth-value(s) of open formulas, I'm going to give a somewhat long-winded answer.

**Deductive systems.** There are a variety of [deductive systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicate_logic#Deductive_systems) for the predicate calculus. Without getting into the weeds, they all share the same goal. Namely, if all models $M$ satisfying a bunch of formulas $\Gamma$ (notation: $M\models\Gamma$) also satisfy $\varphi$, then the deductive system should provide a purely syntactic way to deduce $\varphi$ from $\Gamma$ (notation: $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$).

A "subgoal": one should be able to convert natural-language mathematical proofs into formal proofs.

**Inference rules.** This article lists [four rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Rules_of_classical_predicate_calculus) for the classical predicate calculus. Let's look at two in more detail: universal generalization (UG), and universal instantiation (UI). You'll find them both at work in the example proof in [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

**Universal instantiation** is easier to understand. A natural-language proof might say, "We know (or have assumed) that $\varphi(x)$ holds for all $x$, so in particular it must hold for this element $t$." Formally $t$ would be a term and $x$ a variable, so (UI) takes the form "Infer $\varphi(t)$ from $\forall x\varphi(x)$". (The article lists some restrictions, needed to avoid pitfalls.)

**Universal generalization** shows up in natural language proofs in this way. One starts by laying out the hypotheses $\Gamma$. Next: "Let $x$ be some element." Then some reasoning, concluding that $\varphi(x)$ holds. Finally: "But since $x$ was an arbitrary element, $\forall x \varphi(x)$ is true (still assuming $\Gamma$)."

The article mentions the essential restriction that $x$ not occur free in $\Gamma$, since then $x$ would not be an arbitrary element. (E.g., if our assumptions included the formula $\exists n(x=2n)$, then $x$ would have to be even.)

Harking back to your earlier question, you can now see the usefulness of the convention mentioned in my answer.

**Proof that $\forall x(y=5x)$ is false** for all choices of $y$ (in $\mathbb{R}$). The natural-language argument goes like this: "If this holds for all $x$, it must hold in particular for $x=1$. So we've shown that $y=5$: that's the only choice of $y$ making the claim true. But likewise, if it holds for all $x$, it must hold for $x=-1$, and so $y=-5$. We've now shown that $y=5$ *and* that $y=-5$, which is a contradiction."

A formal proof would be pretty long, but you can see the skeleton. $\forall x(y=5x)$ is our hypothesis, added on to $\Gamma$. ($\Gamma$ consists of the field theory axioms plus some stuff specific to $\mathbb{R}$.) Using UI twice, plus $\Gamma$, you can show formally $y=5$ and also $y=-5$, or finally $5=-5$. This is a contradiction, so the rules of propositional calculus allow you to conclude $\neg\forall x(y=5x)$. We have now "discharged" the hypothesis. That is, the conclusion has been shown to follow just from $\Gamma$. So using UG, we conclude $\forall y(\neg\forall x(y=5x))$.

---

Now, what about the semantic interpretation of these inference rules?

The goal of a deduction system, as I said, is to capture semantic implications. Suppose $M\models\Gamma$ implies $M\models\varphi$; we want to have $\Gamma\vdash\varphi$. Initially assume $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ have no free variables.

The deductive-semantic correspondence is clearest, I think, with so-called [natural deduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Natural_deduction_systems) systems. Here each line of a deduction is written
$$\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\vdash\psi$$
with the semantics "$M\models\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$ implies $M\models\psi$". Again, this is with no free variables.

What if one of the $\varphi$'s or $\psi$ contains a free variable? In that case, the simplest approach is to **expand** the model $M$ by adding a new constant to the language, say $c_y$ for a free variable $y$. An expanded model $(M,c_y)$ assigns a value to $c_y$. There will be many expansions $(M,c_y)$ of a given model $M$. (Same idea for many free variables.)

To say $M\models\psi(y)$ means that *all* of the expansions $(M,c_y)\models\psi(c_y)$. Note that $\psi(c_y)$ is a closed formula. And $\varphi_1(y),\ldots,\varphi_n(y)\vdash\psi(y)$ means that for all models $(M,c_y)$, if $(M,c_y)\models\varphi_1(c_y),\ldots,\varphi_n(c_y)$ then $(M,c_y)\models\psi(c_y)$.

Finally, the UI rule takes the form "From $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\vdash\forall y\varphi(y)$ infer $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\vdash\varphi(t)$", and the UG rule the form "from $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\vdash\varphi(y)$ infer $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n\vdash\forall y\varphi(y)$", subject to the proviso that $y$ doesn't occur free anywhere in $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_n$.

Comment: Thank you Michael. When we are working with the open formula $\forall x (y=5x)$ you seem to be treating $y$ like some sort of constant, but can $y$ not take any value as it's free?

Comment: We started the proof by adding the hypothesis $\forall x(y=5x)$ to our axioms $\Gamma$. So now $y$ is no longer completely arbitrary, but must satisfy this hypothesis, at least until we "discharge" this hypothesis. That's from the deductive system standpoint. The semantic (model-theory) is a little harder to explain. I may add another paragraph later today or tomorrow about this.

Comment: Bear in mind I'm trying to summarize both deductive rules and semantics in a few paragraphs. Ebbinghaus, Flum, and Thomas take about 10 pages to explain the deduction part in their *Mathematical Logic* (2nd ed., UTM). Mendelson's *Introduction to Mathematical Logic* takes nearly 30 pages, blending together the syntax and semantics. Other textbooks will be similar.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the actual reasoning of the proof that the open formula is always false, the way that I understand it, for the formula to be false we want all choices of $y$ to result in a false statement. You have shown that two different values of $x$ require two different values of $y$ for the formula to be true. We never said that $y$ was constant so this seems ok.

Comment: The proper proof to me seems the fact that the ONLY correct choice of $y$ is $5$ when $x$ is swapped for $1$ so we can't have it true for ALL possible $y$.

Comment: "You have shown that two different values of $x$ require two different values of $y$ for the formula to be true. We never said that $y$ was constant so this seems ok." This applies to $y=5x$ but not to $\forall x(y=5x)$. For the latter, once you've chosen $y$, *every choice* of $x$ has to result in a correct equation. So I'm entitled to pick two different values of $x$ and can demand that *the same* $y$ works with both of them

Comment: "The proper proof..." I agree that this is a convincing natural language proof. The question is, how to convert it to a formal proof using some particular deductive system? Perhaps there is another way, but the one I sketched is valid.

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh it all clicked, I have been thinking of this as "choose $y$ then if all $5x$ equals $y$ we are done" but you are just as allowed to "choose $x$ then find $y$ for which its true and in an "ideal" world we would find that all possible choices of $y$ work for all possible choices of $x$ (of course this is rubbish and never happens). In addition to this, when we leave $y$ free is there an implicit $\forall$ quantifier or is $y$ just taken to be one number?

Comment: "So I'm entitled to pick two different values of $x$
 and can demand that the same $y$
 works with both of them" can we also say So I'm entitled to pick two different values of $x$
 and can demand that ALL $y$ works for them (this includes the case where both $y$'s are the same)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147821/discussion-between-michael-weiss-and-mathguy).